# Storing archetypes with maven in different ways

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

To get the hang of maven.
In downloaded commons-cli.
An uncompiled Apache cli helper.

I created a new maven project and Yanked all the uncompiled code in it.
Like so:

```
  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-
  quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This created:

```
commons-cli/
   src/
     main/
       java/
         cli/
           *.java <- all the java code.
```

Now run:

```
 mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

This creates:

```
      generated-sources/
         archetype/
           src/
             main/
             test/
           target/
           pom.xml
```

In this pom.xml:

```
   <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-archetype</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>

   <name>test-archetype</name>
```

Now:

```
  cd target/generated-sources/archetype/
```

and

```
  mvn clean install
```

Now I hava a jar in my .m2/ folder and I can not use it as a dependecy.
Becuase the code is uncompiled.

My quistion is:

How can I just have a .jar with compiled and usable code (.class)added to my local repo?
And use it without the java code.

How can I have just the java code to be added to my repo,
Just as maven-archetype-quickstart ?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow confusing, but I try to answer it as best as I can:

Archetypes are blueprints for projects: You use them to create a new project, but you do not put much source code inside them.

You create a compiled jar by calling `mvn clean install`. It writes the jar with compiled classes to the local repository. If you build such a jar, you can add side artifacts for "sources" and "javadoc". These will also be put into the local repository.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. Actually I was asking 2 questions. 1. How can I store blueprinst with uncompiled java code. Just as the maven-archetype-quickstart. So no jar and no *.class files. Just a blueprint. 2. How can I store compiled *.class files inside a jar. Just so that I can use it as a dependency. Could you give me an example hot to perform 1 & 2? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html . But it seems strange to me that you want to store source code in an archetype. This looks a lot like unnecessary code duplication.  2. just call mvn clean install in the directory of your pom.

Comment: No source code in maven repo? How about: mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong.core.utils -DartifactId=dateUtils -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
?The maven-archetype-quickstart? This is a handy way to save "starters". Isn't it? I thought this was the maven idea. Also with dependency management.

Comment: Ok, you could put some "empty" classes into the archetype, but not real, finished code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

It was easier than I thought.
Instead of above example. 
I started with

```
mvn archetype:generate
  -DgroupId=[your project's group id]
  -DartifactId=[your project's artifact id]
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-archetype
```

put code in files.

Then clean etc. and compile:

```
mvn clean install
```

And modify the

```
 src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
```

compiled code packaged:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org   
/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0   
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd" 
name="commons-cli"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin  
/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<fileSets>
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>org/apache/commons/cli</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.class</include>
    <!--
<include>**/*.html</include>
-->
  </includes>
</fileSet>
 <!--
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/test/java</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
 -->
```

just code:

```
   <archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-
 plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
 instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-
 plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-
 1.0.0.xsd">
  <id>quickstart</id>
  <sources>
    <source>src/main/java/*.java</source>
  </sources>
  <testSources>
    <source>src/test/java/*.java</source>
  </testSources>
</archetype>
```

code and packaged:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <archetype-descriptor xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org 
 /plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"   
 name="commons-cli"
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin
 /archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<fileSets>
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/main/java</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
    <include>**/*.html</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/test/java</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

It's just this configuration in archetype.xml... 
I haven't tested it yet. But this should do the trick. I hope.:)
Thank's JF Meier.